# fac value in bmesh.utils.edge_split

Tags: python, bmesh

Not massively familiar with blender and looking at:
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.utils.html?highlight=edge_split#bmesh.utils.edge_split

It's not clear what the value of the 'fac' argument is supposed to be?
Is it a 3d coord? (x, y, z) or something else, like a fraction of the total length of the edge?

What's a good way to calculate it? As examples there's this:
https://github.com/lijenstina/mesh_extra_tools/blob/c90634a024ab8d531751df873d33dbe905d0ca13/mesh_extrude_and_reshape.py#L217

But want to confirm calculating the distance between the edge's two vertices is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'fac' is a percent of the edge length, considered from the vertex indicated in the call.

For instance, if you run the code below on an edge suite, you'll see the growing percents applied on a length of 2 meters:

[image]

```
import bpy, bmesh


obj = bpy.context.object

if obj is not None:

    prevMode = obj.mode

    try:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)

        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( obj.data )

        edgeCount = len(bm.edges)

        for i, e in zip( range(edgeCount), sorted( bm.edges, key=lambda e: e.verts[0].co[2] ) ): #Indexes and sorted edges from bottom to top
            fac = (i+1) / 10
            print(fac)
            ne, nv = bmesh.utils.edge_split( e, e.verts[0], fac)
            print(ne,nv)

    finally:   
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=prevMode, toggle=False)
```